# Style Bottom and Left calc via JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

**disclaimer**: (solved): i simply forgot an attribute, as pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65531072/14824067 .

---

**Original question:**

I wrote a much bigger code but for testing purposes I broke it down to a test code.
Maybe it's a very small mistake -but I can't find it.

Do you see what I am missing?

WHAT I WANT TO DO: **Set the top and bottom gap via js    - it should work- I did it before - I only have to calculate it in the big program - and hence I use % and use the css "calc"-function**

The test code is as follows:

```html
       <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>test</title>
            </head>
        
            <body>
                
                <p id="hi">hey</p>
                
                
            </body>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById('hi').style.display= "block";
                        document.getElementById('hi').style.bottom= "calc( 50% "+" + "+" 20% )";
                        document.getElementById('hi').style.left=   "calc( 50% "+" + "+" 20% )";
                    </script>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear why you don't want to use css.

The rules you create with js can only work with `position: absolute` as an option. Add this line of js code to set absolute positioning:

```
document.getElementById('hi').style.position = "absolute";
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <p id="hi">hey</p>
</body>
  <script>
  document.getElementById('hi').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('hi').style.bottom = "calc( 50% "+" + "+" 20% )";
  document.getElementById('hi').style.left = "calc( 50% "+" + "+" 20% )";
  document.getElementById('hi').style.position = "absolute";
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `left` with `marginLeft` and combined the strings and the code seems to work fine.

`document.getElementById('hi').style.marginLeft= " calc(50% + 20%) ";`